# Possible unintended reference comparison issue

Tags: c#, winforms

May I ask what it might cause when I didn't fix this?

Second question is what is the possibility to fix it.

I'm receiving it with following code:

```
if (cb_vyber_cena.SelectedItem == "Jiná"){ cena_zaj = txt_jin_cena.Text;}
```

I get following warning:

> Possible unintended reference comparison; to get a value comparison,
>   cast the left hand side to type 'string'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`==` is overloaded as a `static` operation, not as a `virtual` operation. If `SelectedItem` is typed as `object`, this will only ever perform a *reference* equality check. If you intend to compare the values *as strings*, you need to add a cast:

```
if ((string)cb_vyber_cena.SelectedItem == "Jiná") {
    cena_zaj = txt_jin_cena.Text;
}
```

This will allow it to use the `==` overloaded by the `string` type. Note that if you aren't sure that `SelectedItem` is a `string` you might need a type test too:

```
if ((cb_vyber_cena.SelectedItem as string) == "Jiná") {
    cena_zaj = txt_jin_cena.Text;
}
```

Alternatively, you could use the `virtual` implementation of `Equals`:

```
if ("Jiná".Equals(cb_vyber_cena.SelectedItem)) {
    cena_zaj = txt_jin_cena.Text;
}
```

Noting that I used `"Jiná"` on the left hand side to avoid issues if `SelectedItem` is `null`.